# Redefining \dh gives problem with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, font-encodings

I would like to define `\renecommand{\dh}{d.\,h.\xspace}` which would help me to enter d.h. correctly in a German text. Problem: doing this before `hyperref` gives the T1-default, doing it after hyperref everything is ok. I have seen the questions about T1 and OT1 which is related, but not directly, to my problem. I can put the command behind `hyperref` but I am not sure whether this is the right way to solve my problem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{scrartcl}       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{xspace}
% not working
%\renewcommand{\dh}{d.\,h.\xspace}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
% working
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\dh}{d.\,h.\xspace}

\begin{document}
\dh
\end{document}
```

Comment: well if you want to do it, you should do if after every package which sets up font commands (as hyperref does).  But you will break the original definition of \dh. Why don't you use another command name instead?

Comment: .. since I am not using the symbol behind the original \dh and since \dh = d.h. looks just the same. A good reason for me doing this. Thanks for mentioning the font-commands in hyperref. I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're right (of course), I've got TL2017. Sometimes I forget that...

Comment: @campa but why did you delete your answer? In the main point it was quite correct, the encoding doesn't matter.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: With `\DeclareTextSymbol{\ddh}{T1}{'360}` I get the original back. Or is this not a good solution?

Comment: well hyperref will not know it so it won't work in the bookmarks. I would use acro or something like this. Then you can use \ac{dh}, and even switch between long and short if needed. And you don't need xspace.